# Need to add extra amount for purchasing if it is less than minimum amount

Tags: php, magento

I have a magento site. I need to add extra amount to the purchase if the customer purchasing less than an amount, means, if the item is lesser than Rs.500 I need to add Rs. 100 extra. How does it possible in magento?

Comment: i think you can do this with cart rules in magento admin

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using observer event

```
<sales_quote_add_item>
```

Comment: do you still have any doubt??

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys for helping me to sorting it out.

I did it using system --> configuration --> shipping methods --> table rates.